# ipad logo while submitting app

Tags: iphone, ipad, submission

Hi I have to submit my first iPhone app. I have tested it on iPod touch and iPhone. While submitting, is it necessary to add the iPad logo. if yes how to do it. my application is a small utility application...and I have not programmed it keeping iPad GUI guidelines in mind for example it doesn't have the landscape layout.

how is it normally...if I submit an app is it automatically considered for iPad as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your info.plist specifies which devices you support.  Apps build with SDK level prior to 3.2 can't support iPad.  You only need the iPad icon if your app supports iPad, so you will be ok.

HIG strongly recommends landscape support for iPad, but it isn't required; it isn't essential for iPhone apps, either.

Comment: thanks paul..I have submitted the app already... i will update here about the progress.

Answer (score 1):

iPad app icon is `72 x 72` pixels, png format (that's your application icon)

the AppStore icon is `512 x 512` pixels (that's required when submitting via itunesconnect.apple.com)

landscape support is optional.

Comment: doest that mean ..i need to put the ipad icon also in the binary..even  I have not create the lanscape support.

Comment: i have the target SDK as OS 3.0 which actually doesn't have iPad support

Comment: no, ipad icon (72 x 72) is optional. icon itself is optional. you don't need to include _any_ icon if you don't want to ;-)

Comment: thats not funny :) any way thanks for your comment. I hope some one else can answer probably my stupid question..

Answer (score -2):

You should not include any Apple trademarked images including the iPhone and iPad logos. Also, your app could be rejected if it doesn't support the landscape orientation unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: i do not use any trademark apple logo...I have created my own logo for iPhone app and configured in info.plist, which is 57x57 format. but my binary doesn't have any 50x50 and 72x72 logo for iPad. I dont want it actually. For the landscape layout..its a small utility application which doesnt need any landscape layout. I have seenn 100s of apps which dont have landscape support.

Comment: Oh, when you use the word "logo" you meant "icon." Yeah, that confused me. So if you have the 57x57 and 72x72 icons, that's fine.